# Find nested array-object from rethinkdb in feathers JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, rethinkdb, feathersjs

I have a data set like follows-

```
[{

    "allowedusers": ["paul@abc.com"],
    "id": "1"

  },{

    "allowedusers": ["kmahera@abc.com","rbajaniya@abc.com"],
    "id": "2"
   },{

    "allowedusers": ["whatever@abc.com","rbajaniya@abc.com"],
   "id": "3"
}]
```

and I have  a Query like this -

`http://localhost:3030/flowz$limit=5&allowedusers[$in[]=rbajaniya@abc.com&$skip=0&$select[]=id&$select[]=alloweduser`.

But I am not getting all the objects that contain  `rbajaniya@abc.com` . How can I craft my query to get this. I want to get id=2 and id=3 in response .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$in` is to check a single value in the database against a list of possible values. What you are looking for is the other way around which can be done through the [feathers-rethinkdb](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb) specific [$contains operator](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-rethinkdb#contains):

```
http://localhost:3030/flowz?$limit=5&allowedusers[$contains]=rbajaniya@abc.com&$skip=0&$select[]=id&$select[]=alloweduser
```