# In Featherjs NeDB cant query document to check if array contains element

Tags: node.js, json, nosql, feathersjs, nedb

Here is an example datastore:

```
  {
    "Participants": [
      {
        "ParticipantID": "peaches",
        "Amount": 10,
        "ParentUser": "11111111"
      },
      {
        "ParticipantID": "apples",
        "Amount": 20,
        "ParentUser": "22222222"
      }
    ],
    "BillingName": "test person",
    "Last4": "****",
    "Date": "2019-08-13T20:25:19.197Z",
    "_id": "IYboK0SeNIvbf7O0"
  },
  {
    "Participants": [
      {
        "ParticipantID": "pears",
        "Amount": 10,
        "ParentUser": "11111111"
      },
      {
        "ParticipantID": "bananas",
        "Amount": 20,
        "ParentUser": "22222222"
      }
    ],
    "BillingName": "a different person",
    "Last4": "****",
    "Date": "2019-08-13T20:25:19.197Z",
    "_id": "ASDboK0SeNIvbf7O0"
  }
```

**What I want** is to query the database for documents that contain a specific `ParticipantID` in the `Participants` array.

For example querying for "peaces" or "apples" would return the first document. "pears" or "bananas" would return the second.

**My issue is** I cant figure out a way to basically do `.includes()` on an array in featherjs/neDB.

I tried simplifying it to a simple array of numbers to avoid the complexity of the nested object, but I just cant figure out how to search an array. `$in` operator receives an array as input and checks the values against the database. Its the opposite of what I need.

**What i've tried:**

The closest answer I could find was: **[Find nested array-object from rethinkdb in feathers JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782202/find-nested-array-object-from-rethinkdb-in-feathers-js)**

Unfortunately neDB != rethinkDB and `$contains` throws an undefined error.

NeDB documentation: https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/wiki/Finding-documents

Seems to have an example that does what I need of:

```
// Use the dot-notation to navigate arrays of subdocuments
db.find({ "completeData.planets.name": "Mars" }, function (err, docs) {
  // docs contains document 5
});
```

But when I try to use "find" in a query in featherjs literally nothing happens. No error, nothing. I feel like I must be missing something super simple.

I would post code but literally all of it is just desperate tests and wouldn't be helpful. I spent hours on this and really be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!!!

This: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-nedb 
pointed me to the whitelist field. Add $elemMatch to that list. NeDB  query parameters do not just work out of the box. You must add any you want to use to the whitelist.

Then for the query do this:

```
{ Participants: { $elemMatch: { ParticipantID: 'peaches'} } }
```

For example. elemMatch documented here. https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#array-fields

I'm so stupid. Hopefully this saves someone time.